# Searching JSON value multiple levels deep

Tags: javascript, json, search

I have the following data object, and eventually there will be more similar ones within `entities`:

```
function loadCardLibrary() {
    var cardLibrary = {
        entities: [
            {
                name: "Spareparts",
                values: {
                    sickness: 0,
                    attack: 0,
                    scrap: 3,
                    manaCost: 0
                },
                apply: [
                    applyCreature("Mech"),
                    applyHealth(1),
                    applyNoAttack(true)
                ]
            }
        ]
    };
    return cardLibrary;
}
```

I am trying to write a function (see this [example](http://repl.it/l3s/2/)) to search for a `name` value, then go in that object and search to check for a specific `apply` value, like so:

```
function checkHasNoAttack(entityName) {
    for (var entity in cardLibrary.entities) {
        if (cardLibrary.entities[entity].name === entityName) {
            // for debugging
            console.log(cardLibrary.entities[entity]);
            console.log(); // blank line
            for (var applied in cardLibrary.entities[entity].apply) {
                if (cardLibrary.entities[entity].apply[applied].applyNoAttack === true) {
                    console.log(entityName + " cannot attack.");
                } else {
                    console.log("test");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I call it right after, like this:

```
var canItAttack = checkHasNoAttack("Spareparts");
```

...this is the result:

```
{ 
    name: 'Spareparts',
    values: {
        sickness: 0,
        attack: 0,
        scrap: 3,
        manaCost: 0
    },
    apply: [ 'Mech', 1, true ]
}

test
```

Instead of `test` which comes from the `else`, I am trying to log the get it to respond to the first `if` statement, and log:

> Spareparts cannot attack.

With the understanding that more complicated logic will eventually replace the `console.log` there I really need this to work, but have been tinkering with it and I just can't seem to get it right. Any help very appreciated!

Comment: Isn't your `apply` an array? `cardLibrary.entities[entity].apply[applied].applyNoAttack` will most likely be `undefined`.

Comment: I guess it might be, what am I missing? It did get some `undefined` errors writing it a bit differently. Can you find a workaround? I provided a link to run the code, if you do know a workaround, please do post an answer!

Comment: I think you might want to change your `apply` to `apply: {applyCreature: applyCreature("Mech"), applyHealth: applyHealth(1), applyNoAttack: applyNoAttack(true)}`

Comment: @Passerby I think your advice could be an answer instead of comments, if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
function check(a) {
    var result = null;
    cardLibrary.entities.forEach(function(b){
        if (b.name === a) {
            if (b.apply[2] === true) {
                console.log(a + " cannot attack!");
            } else {
                console.log("test");
            }
            result = b;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

`apply` is an array, you have to use `[2]` to select that value

---

Arrays do an ugly job at this, I recommend modifying your `apply` into an object like:

```
apply: {
    creature: applyCreature("Mech"),
    health: applyHealth(1),
    noAttack: applyNoAttack(true)
}
```

Then you can use this code:

```
function check(a) {
    var result = null;
    cardLibrary.entities.forEach(function(b){
        if (b.name === a) {
            if (b.apply.noAttack === true) {
                console.log(a + " cannot attack!");
            } else {
                console.log("test");
            }
            result = b;
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I really want to be able to reference the `apply` things by name, rather than by index... should they then be made into individual sub-objects instead of values in an array?

Comment: @Phrancis Yeah, definitely. Arrays aren't really designed for this because it can be resorted, etc.

Comment: Thanks again, looks like I'll be changing my JSON then, glad this was caught early before I converted all my data to JSON!